# I am fasing problem to create react app (error npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall lstat)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

**$ npx create-react-app youtube**
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-24T08_52_01_732Z-debug-0.log

please tell me solution

Answer (score 1):

Manually create the C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm directory yourself.
That should stop that error from occurring (it did for me).

Answer (score 0):

This is your current folder or directory:

```
C:\Users\warrior\AppData\Roaming
```

You can create the folder or directory yourself manually:

```
C:\Users\warrior\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because you do not have the npm folder in your 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming'.

To resolve this problem:

1. Install any npm package globally e.g. npm i -g npm-check-updates
2. Check to see if you now have "npm" folder created in 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming'
3. Because all globally installed packages by default, are listed in 'C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Roaming\npm, the missing npm folder would be created.
4. Run the create react app command again, and you are sorted.

Note: this solution is for windows. If you are using a different OS, you can try upgrading npm to latest version, and see if it fixes your problem.